# How can I get the firestore data with a date range, boolean, and not equals?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have these sessions and I wanted to retrieve the data of these users with:

```
session1 == true
session2 == false
```

and also get the data of those that did not choose `meeting2` or `selected !== meeting2`:

This is the firestore document:
[image]

And how can I query it where DateEnd is greater than the date of today .

This is how I query it in firestore. So far, it isn't working.

```
componentDidMount() {
    firestore
      .collection("users")
      .where("aptment.session2", "==", false)
      .where("aptment.selection", "!=", "meeting2")
       //DateEnd greater than today's date
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const users = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          users.push({
            "User ID": doc.id, 
            Address: data.address,
          });
        });
        this.setState({ users: users });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Firebase documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

So you can't have a `>=` condition on the `DateEnd` field when you already have a `!=` condition on the `aptment.selection` field. You will have to do one of these condition in the query, and then perform the rest of the filtering in your application code.

Comment: Ohh alright. Thank you